# Where can I find good level creation tutorials for Little Big Planet 2?

Tags: little-big-planet-2

I would like to know how to create better/more advanced levels in little big planet 2. However, the in-game tutorials don't explain some things (like how to create cars, gates, etc). I think that the in-game tutorials just overview what tools you can use, not how to use them.

I would like to have something I can print to read while I create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LittleBigPlanet Central has a pretty comprehensive list of tutorials.](http://www.lbpcentral.com/forums/showthread.php?46908-LittleBigPlanet-2-Tutorials-and-Games)

Comment: Awesome list and very helpful